# Render child component only when parent's network call promise is resolved in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am not sure if it's anti-pattern, I've created a HOC at routes level and fetching user details in it like this:

```
class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    const { component : RouteComponent, checkAuth, ...rest } = this.props
    const route = (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) => {
          return checkAuth() === true
            ? <RouteComponent {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{pathname : '/login'}} />
        }}
      />
    )

    return route
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { store } = this.props
    const { user } = store.getState()
    const accessToken = getCookie('access_token')

    if (!user.userInfo && accessToken) {
      store.dispatch(getUserDetails(accessToken)) // Setting user details in redux store.
    }
  }
}

const routes = (checkAuth, store) => (
  <div className='app grid'>
    <ConnectedNavbarContainer />
    <div className='col'>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact={true} from='/' to='/dashboard' />
        <Route path='/login' component={ConnectedLoginContainer} />
        <PrivateRoute 
          store={store}
          checkAuth={checkAuth} 
          path='/:id/dashboard' 
          component={ConnectedDashboardContainer} 
        />
        <PrivateRoute 
          store={store}
          checkAuth={checkAuth} 
          path='/select-store' 
          component={ConnectedSelectStoreContainer} 
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Observe in `componentWillMount` function of `PrivateRoute`, I am fetching user details and saving it in redux store. Now the problem is `getUserDetails` is async call and the child component of `PrivateRoute` will make network calls to render that page and those network calls need userID which will be present in the `getUserDetails` call's response.

Now I want the child component to wait until the `getUserDetails` call is resolved. I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an action that will set a state in the redux store to reflect that user details are being retrieved. This will enable to child component to know that user details are not ready yet, and display an appropriate message (e.g. 'loading...' or 'initializing...').

When user details are retrieved, the above state should be updated appropriately. If the retrieval of user details has failed, fire another action that will set the state to error (and clearing the 'loading in process' state), to enable the child to display an error message.